# Running sqlmap against a parameter inside a parameter

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have a domain in the format: example.com?host=http://anotherexample.com?bar=1

I want to attack the "bar" param, but sqlmap (correctly) parses the second url as a value of the foo param. Therefore I can't select the bar variable with the -p argument.

Any way around this?

In response to one answer, the resulting command is like so:

sqlmap -v -p user -u "example.com?host=?user=1" --prefix="http://anotherexample.com/debug"

This isn't valid, as the first param must be a ? for the url to be valid, and the remaining params but be &'s.

Comment: you specify the parameter to attack as "user" but want to attack the parameter "host". If you change that, and set the prefix and suffix accordingly, it should work

Answer (score 2):

**Use the sqlmap pre- and suffix options**

Sqlmap offers the options "--prefix" and "suffix" that according to the manual

```
--prefix=PREFIX     Injection payload prefix string
--suffix=SUFFIX     Injection payload suffix string
```

can be used to prepend or append a string to the injection payload.

So if you run your query with:

```
python sqlmap.py -p host -u "example.com?host=" --prefix "http://anotherexample.com?bar=1" --suffix "&restoftheurl=whatever"
```

sqlmap should construct the parameter in the format you are looking for.

So for the example injection payload `' AND 7235=7235--` the options create a request to the url

```
example.com?host=http://anotherexample.com?bar=1' AND 7235=7235--&restoftheurl=whatever
```

(in the real request the special characters and spaces of the URL parameter will be URL encoded).

Note: You might need to URL encode the special characters in the pre- and suffix options.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I have updated my question with more information :D